# Type 'CSSStyleDeclaration' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'

Tags: typescript

I created a function for styling the DOM `element` at once

```js
function css(element: HTMLElement, designs: Record<CSSStyleDeclaration, string>): void {
    for (let design in designs) {
        element.style[design] = designs[design]
    }
}
```

**What I want?**

I want to **autocomplete** the property names as I type. For example

```js
css(someElement, {
  backg...: 'red' // I want all possible css properties that starts with backg like we have in vscode
})
```

**What I am getting!**

`Type 'CSSStyleDeclaration' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.`

The above error not breaking any thing but it is not auto completing the property name.

Comment: TypeScript does not allow using objects as keys. You can only bypass this by using `any`. It is generally not advised to use objects as keys, since technically only the object reference is used. When you try to access an object-key later with an identical object, it may not work when it has a different reference.

Comment: @TobiasS. that's true but the main motive is to get _autocomplete functionality_ any other way around to achieve that?

Comment: Note that your loop can be replaced with `Object.assign(element.style, designs)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
function css(element: HTMLElement, designs: Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>): void {
    for (let design in designs) {
        element.style[design] = designs[design]!
    }
}
```

`CSSStyleDeclaration` actually already contains all the properties we need. No need to use a `Record` here. Since all properties in `CSSStyleDeclaration` are required, we also need add `Partial` to make all properties optional.

Now the auto-completion works.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/FDBmFcDsGMBcEsD2kAE0DO6AUBTANjgLY6SwBcKAEgCoCyAMgKIHGkA0KAJjuvAOaR0FAAoBDAE4JReADwBhAMpLYATwIARHNDwTRCZAD4AlBQBuieJxQBvYCnspQicSiwFYXHv1TxU3XgLoRjZ2DmH4RCSwAHToqgQA2v7eALooALyeAYJJXgIpAISh9gC%20wGXA0MhxKOiIxMyRpBQ0DNSiAEYEjawemdYlKKLoQ5AqIBjYdQ0sURy29h2i0ADWfOKIUJwUAOTiOJw7KAD0xygAkigA7qKkQ3h4KAAOiJjwXThomM8bTziS8B4KFgAAs9LVYBJYCMrvBQSglqs%20Cg8PAVp8rp8waZPr4UKZ0FVuOUjEA)

Comment: Thanks! but why `!` is on the object value?

Comment: Since we made `designs` a `Partial` type where every property is optional, `designs[design]` also resolves to `... | undefined`. But `element.style[design]` does not accept `undefined`. You might think that since we are using a `for ... in` loop, `designs[design]` can not be `undefined`, but `designs` could have properties which are explictely set to `undefined` which should also show up in the `for ... in` loop.

Comment: I know its been long! But I have a question can I also add autocomplete for possible values for `position` and many other keys like we can do in `css`.